# How to apply grouping in SSRS RDL report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have to create report SSRS RDL.I am new to report.

Can anybody suggest me how to design report OR apply grouping so that it looks alike as given below format:

[image]

and following records are coming from database:

[image]

Where

Total AA = 3(1+2),4(3+1)

Total A = 8(3+5),5(4+1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either right click the cell and select `Add Group` and then `Parent Group` under `Row Group` or right click your details group under `Row Groups` window.

EDIT:

Attached some images showing the process:

[image]

Then you select the field used to group and if you want to add a header/footer.

[image]

For your total you can use [Sum(FieldName)].

It will sum only the data inside that group.